# Local variables and formal parameters with same name in c++?

Tags: java, c++

In java, class variables and formal parameters can have the same name and the class variable is referenced with the "this" keyword. Is there something similar in c++?

Example in java

```
public class A {
    private int x;
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very easy to test...

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `this->` operator ! Don't hold me down to it !

Comment: @StackFlowed Thank you. If you submit this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Will that is done !

Comment: @StackFlowed Thanks. Its making me wait 8 minutes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is `this->`

Answer (score 5):

In C++ it is :

```
this->x = x
```

the 'this' pointer is used to retrieve the object's x hidden by the local variable 'x'